# Date Reminders from server side response

Tags: javascript, date

Here is my json array coming from server side

```
[{payment_date: "Jun 25th 2015",
 amount: 30.43},{payment_date: "Jun 25th 2015",
 amount: 100.23},
{payment_date: "Jun 22th 2015",
 amount: 10.03},
{payment_date: "Jun 20th 2015",
 amount: 56.43}]
```

Here is a the case suppose i had made a payment on this month 20th,22nd and 25th and the server response gives me set of reminder dates for next month.If he do not have any other payments after 25th i need to show him an alert for jun 20th later on jun 22nd and then on 25th. Please suggest me how can show him a reminder.

Comment: This question is not very clear. Please clarify. How would you like the reminder displayed? How are you pulling data from the server? Check out JSFiddle.

Comment: Using restful services i'll be getting above json response i'll use a alert box to display to user like your next payment date is so and so.

Comment: How would you check for payments after 25th? Do you intend to use the current date to decide when to show this information?  Please edit your question with the information it is easier to understand. Thanks!

Comment: I thought in this way if he had no payments after 25th. Will sort the array of date and compare it with current date and should get the next date means like 20th as per my say.But i really do not know how?